# Force server to serve different file than the mentioned in the link

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Situation: You sent an Email campaign containing a download link and by mistake, you added a link to the wrong PDF file. Now thousand of readers will download that wrong file.

Workaround: Adding a rule in the .htaccess file to force the server to serve the different file.

The rule I used and did not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/oldpath/file.pdf https://www.example.com/newpath/file.pdf
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the rule like this instead near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldpath/file\.pdf$ /newpath/file.pdf [L]
```

This *interally rewrites* the request from `/oldpath/file.pdf` to `/newpath/file.pdf`. The client still thinks they are getting `/oldpath/file.pdf`, but `/newpath/file.pdf` is served instead. This is not a "redirect".

If you specifically want to *externally redirect* the request instead then add the `R` flag to the above `RewriteRule` directive. eg. `[R=302,L]` - to explicitly serve a 302 (temporary) redirect.

---

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> Redirect 301 https://www.example.com/oldpath/file.pdf https://www.example.com/newpath/file.pdf
> ```

`RewriteEngine` and `Redirect` belong to different modules, mod_rewrite and mod_alias respectively - they are not related (only in so far as you can perform redirects with both modules).

The `Redirect` directive matches against a root-relative (starting with a slash) URL-path, so the above absolute URL will never match. It would need to be written like this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpath/file.pdf https://www.example.com/newpath/file.pdf
```